# Upload dSYM to crashlytics from window

Tags: xamarin, jenkins, xamarin.ios, continuous-integration, crashlytics

I develop app by Xamarin.IOS and want to use crashlytics. I use CI by Jenkins based on Windows. How can I automatically upload dSYM files to crashlytics from windows machine? I try find any public API for that, but found nothing.

I have workaround: Upload dsym to mac and use fastlane

Is it only one way for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here and you're correct that using Fastlane as a workaround is the best solution.